# pt-online-schema-change error creating triggers

Tags: mysql, index

I am trying to add an index with pt-online-schema-change. The dry-run succeeds, but I am stuck at creating triggers. Any help ?

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD INDEX domain_index (domain) USING BTREE" D=master,t=website,u=root --execute --ask-pass
Enter MySQL password: 
No slaves found.  See --recursion-method if host inoopa-storage has slaves.
Not checking slave lag because no slaves were found and --check-slave-lag was not specified.
Operation, tries, wait:
  analyze_table, 10, 1
  copy_rows, 10, 0.25
  create_triggers, 10, 1
  drop_triggers, 10, 1
  swap_tables, 10, 1
  update_foreign_keys, 10, 1
Altering `master`.`website`...
Creating new table...
Created new table master._website_new OK.
Altering new table...
Altered `master`.`_website_new` OK.
2020-06-05T16:02:10 Creating triggers...
2020-06-05T16:12:19 Dropping triggers...
2020-06-05T16:12:19 Dropped triggers OK.
2020-06-05T16:12:19 Dropping new table...
2020-06-05T16:12:19 Dropped new table OK.
`master`.`website` was not altered.
Error creating triggers: 2020-06-05T16:12:19 DBD::mysql::db do failed: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction [for Statement "CREATE TRIGGER `pt_osc_master_website_del` AFTER DELETE ON `master`.`website` FOR EACH ROW DELETE IGNORE FROM `master`.`_website_new` WHERE `master`.`_website_new`.`id` <=> OLD.`id`"] at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 11074, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! There's no way anybody can begin to help you without the DDL for the table as well as all trigger definitions you have on that table! Please provide this information and we may **begin** to be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows a lock wait timeout.

This means you cannot lock the table.

There is always three triggers needed for `pt-osc` on the source table:

- `INSERT` trigger
- `DELETE` trigger
- `UPDATE` trigger

The triggers are not create atomically. They are created one at a time.

If `root@localhost` has `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.*`, you should be able to create the trigger. It looks like the table must have very high read/write traffic.

You will have to clean up as follows:

Kill the pt-osc

Login to MySQL and run

```
USE master
DROP TABLE `_website_new`;
DROP TRIGGER pt_osc_master_website_ins;
DROP TRIGGER pt_osc_master_website_upd;
DROP TRIGGER pt_osc_master_website_del;
```

The, start `pt-osc` over again